# Upload image from blob url to s3 bucket

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, blob, image-uploading, aws-amplify

I get blob URL from the promise [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/0yc6bdno/). Now I want to save this into s3 with `aws-amplify`. Since this is a blob URL, How do I have to push this to s3 bucket?  Following is my code

```
handleSaveImage = (imageUrl) => {
    const imageName = this.getImageName(this.imageRef.src);
    Storage.put(fileName, imageUrl, {
      contentType: contentTypes.IMAGE,
      level: 'private'
    })
      .then(({ key }) => {
        //console.log(key);
        this.setState({ croppedImageUrl: imageUrl });
        //onImageUpload(key);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log('some error occured');
      });
  };

  getImageName = (url) => {
    console.log(url.split('/')[5].split('?')[0]);
    return url.split('/')[5].split('?')[0];
  };
```

Also, Blob URL goes as this `blob:https://fiddle.jshell.net/a0d3d404-e9e3-464d-92eb-5849d1404c08`

Answer (score 2):

How about you fetch the blob, convert it to file object and uploaded it to S3. As for fetching the blob, you can try this [rn-fetch-blob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob). Then converting is quite straight forward.

```
const file = new File([fetchedBlob], "filename");
```

Comment: It was too late but this is the solution I have implemented it